# PCA in R, such that the first eigenvector is constant vector

Tags: r, pca

I am trying to perform PCA in R, forcing the first eigenvector (i.e., the first rotation vector) to be equal to the constant vector. I would like this constant to be 1/sqrt(10). How can I do it in R?